# Autocomplete shows only message N results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate. instead show list

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

my problem is clear.

I'm using jquery autocomplete and i don't know why it shows me only the message:

```
9 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.
```

Without showing me the list of result.

This is my code:

```
<p class="select-c">
     <label for="fcb">Location</label>
     <input id="fcb" name="fcb" type="text">                        
</p>


$("#fcb").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "../ws/city/" + request.term,
                async: true,
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item,key ) {
                        return {
                            label: key,
                            value: item.id_town+"#"+item.id_province
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

with results like:

[image]

What could be the problem??

Comment: What browser/device are you testing on?

Comment: I've tested it on chrome and safari

Comment: Do you see any menu item or nothing at all? It seems that the plugin is working, that message is for ARIA support

Comment: no menu.. nothing.. only that span..

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to replicate this? I am not able to replicate your problem...

Comment: i think that the template that i'm using creates that problem. Can i contact you in private so i can give you the url of my site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your CSS, maybe you are hiding the menu element. Try with:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 10000000;
}
```

Comment: @JackTurky Probably you are **not** importing the CSS from jQuery UI

Comment: css is imported correctly.. but what i need was to show list.. so .. thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 14):

Just check if you are importing the correct css to correct the list rendering

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

---

And if you also want to remove the message, add the following entry after source

```
$("#fcb").autocomplete({
    //your source info
   messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function() {}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11):

```
  .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
            display: none;
        }
```

Comment: If you're intending this to answer the question, please include some text of your own explaining why/how it works in answering the question, not solely code.